# How to receive Facebook App id on a canvas page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, configuration, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

Is it possible to get the Facebook app id on my canvas page?

So I am here: apps.facebook.com/myappspace

and in my index.php I want to get the FB App id now. Is this possible? The only way I figured out was when I can get the signed_request, because a user already authenticated my app.

But let's assume an unauthenticated user visits my canvas page. Any way to get the FB App Id?

P.S.
It's not possible to write it into my php-file, because I use the same code for several Facebook Apps, so I need to find our now what App is used to show individualized content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short this is not possible without getting `signed_request`.

Actually you not really have to place this information in the code, but some configuration files, which should be different for every application instance, have appropriate permissions and without public access for sure.

You can decide which configuration to use based on application hostname/ip (any other way to identify which application it is).

Comment: Ok. So it is not possible to get it. So what I do is basically I save an array in my app which says:
array ("myappspace" => 1234567,
       "mayppspace2" => 9876544, ...);

then in the app I read out the url and map the "myappspace" to the array.
Is that right?

Thanks a lot
PS: 12345 and 98765 are the fb app ids

Comment: it can be done in many ways from `array` containing all your applications credentials (less preferred IMO) to separate files with either ini, php array, any other/custom format... You can decide which one to use setting `ENV` variable passed with web-server or have a map of configs to hostnames (beware that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is passed by client and cannot be fully trusted)... I think you get the idea, the implementation is limited only by your needs and imagination ;)